# Using MySQL Stored Function

Tags: mysql, triggers

Im trying to use mysql store function.
The function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION ChangeHistory(newValue VARCHAR(255), oldValue VARCHAR(255), attributeName VARCHAR(255), action VARCHAR(255), entityId BIGINT(20), modifiedBy BIGINT(20)) RETURNS TINYINT(1)
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   IF newValue != oldValue THEN 
    INSERT INTO ChangeHistoryPlayer
    SET
        action = action,
        timeCreated = now(),
        entityId = entityId,
        modifiedBy= modifiedBy,

        attributeName = attributeName,
        oldValue = oldValue2,
        newValue =  newValue2; 
    END IF;
 RETURN 1;
END
```

Function call in trigger:

```
USE `XXX_admin`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `player_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON `player` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    ChangeHistory(NEW.firstName, OLD.firstName, 'firstName', 'AFTER_UPDATE', NEW.entityId, NEW.modifiedBy);
END
```

The error (after the changeHistoy and before "("  ):

```
syntax error, unexpected '(' expecting ':'
```

Why?

Comment: You really need a function? Why not use procedure and then `CALL ChangeHistory(...);` in trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `player_aupd` after UPDATE 
ON `player` 
FOR EACH row 
begin 
  SELECT Changehistory(new.firstname, old.firstname, 'firstName', 'AFTER_UPDATE' 
         , 
                      new.entityid, new.modifiedby); 
end
```

Adding a select should do the trick!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now when I try to "apply" I get : ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(NEW.firstName, OLD.firstName, 'firstName', .....

Comment: Hmm, the above is valid syntax? When you write 'apply' do you mean test the trigger? Or attempt to create the trigger?

Comment: attempt to create the trigger

Comment: Hmm.. whats happens if you try to execute the function itself?

Comment: Or simply call the function with mock parameters outside of the trigger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62526/discussion-between-lior-and-drew).